# Gridster 2 - EmptyCellClickCallback Can't Access Component Objects - Angular 8

Tags: angular, gridster

I've wired up gridster2 options to enable clicking via empty cells like this:

```
 this.options = {       
    enableEmptyCellClick: true,
    emptyCellClickCallback: this.emptyCellClick,
 }

 add(){
   //
 }

emptyCellClick(event: MouseEvent, item: GridsterItem): void {     
     this.add()
}
```

I get a console error '**this.add is not a function'**.  I can't even access services passed in via the constructor in my component.

I'm assuming the `emptyCellClick callback` is getting initialised before the rest of the component but I've no idea how to solve the problem.

I'm using angular 8.2.12 and gridster2.

Comment: I figured out that I need to bind the callback: this.emptyCellClick = this.emptyCellClick.bind(this);

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of the context of this keyword is different (ie it's not referring to the component class).

Try something like this if possible.

```
this.options = {       
    enableEmptyCellClick: true,
    emptyCellClickCallback: (event: MouseEvent, item: GridsterItem) => this.emptyCellClick(event: MouseEvent, item: GridsterItem),
 }
```

OR as you said binding this is also possible